# Alexa - Allow User To Add Item To Amazon Basket/Cart. Help Needed

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I've posted this question on the Amazon Developer Forums but I'm not getting a response. In the meantime, I thought I'd see if any devs on here can provide any insight or advice:

I’m building an Alexa skill for a client. So far we’ve added the following features to skill and they are successful:

1. Add items to user Todo List
2. Add items to user Shopping List
3. Get permission from user to use Amazon Pay.

We need to be able to give the user the option to add an item to their Amazon basket/cart from the client’s existing Amazon store. I’ve read all the posts/answers related to this issue on the developer forum and all of them were published last year.

The answers I’ve read seem to suggest we can’t add an item to a users Amazon basket/cart.

Is there an update on this for 2019? Can we do this with Amazon Pay or the Account Linking feature?

If not, is it technically possible if we build a custom back-end to work with the skill?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are creating custom skill with ASK. Yes, you can add the product in the cart using Amazon Product Advertising API Please refer blow documentation link for more information. you can do lots of other stuff like modify the cart, adding wishlist, remove the product in the cart. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AddingItemstoaCart.html

Hope this helps.
.

Comment: Thank you for this, that’s very helpful - it’s a shame this API wasn’t referenced In the ASK docs. I am using the ASK-CLI as well as the Jovo Framework, building a custom skill. The Jovo guys haven’t built this feature into the framework yet. However, if it’s possible to add items to the cart and then use the Amazon Pay to complete the purchase, we’ll do it with or without the Jovo framework. Can you confirm if this is possible within an Alexa Skill? Have you built this yourself or know someone who has?

Comment: I developed a similar kind of skill with python flask-ask.  Amazon does not directly provide an API for purchasing products as far as I am aware. still, you can use third-party API https://www.zincapi.com/ to do the purchasing.

Comment: Great, I will look into this further. Really appreciate your help.